# How to write a xls file in 5.0/95 format in R?

Tags: r, xls, xlsxwriter

I need to export data from r in format of 5.0/95 xls file but when I use

```
library(xlsx)
Data = data.frame(col1=LETTERS[1:10], col2=c(1:10))
write.xlsx(Data, "Data.xls", row.names=F)
```

the format of output file is 2003. The data structure is like this

```
dput(Data)
structure(list(col1 = structure(1:10, .Label = c("A", "B", "C",
"D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), class = "factor"), col2 = 1:10), .Names = c("col1",
"col2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide `Data` in a reproducible format (preferably using `dput`) to test ? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: The Excel 5/95 and 2003 xls formats are more or less the same (with some additions in the latter). What issue are you having with the Excel 2003 file that requires an Excel 5 file instead? Are you possibly confusing this with the Excel 2007 format, which is xlsx?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the xlwt library https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/ (for Python) can generate files in Excel 95 format.
In that case, you could use `reticulate` to call it.

Not so easy but maybe the only alternative to achieve it.